# Multi-threading in SWI-Prolog provides little improvement

Tags: multithreading, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a code that carries heavy computations: executing `pred(In, Out)` let's say 64K times where each execution takes 1-10 seconds.

I want to use multi-threaded (64) machine for speeding up the process.
I use [`concurrent_maplist`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=thread%3Aconcurrent_maplist/2) for this:

`concurrent_maplist(pred, List_of_64K_In, List_of_64K_Out).`

I get approx 8 times speed up but not more than that.
I thought the reason was the following notice on [`concurrent_maplist`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=thread%3Aconcurrent_maplist/2):

> Note that the the overhead of this predicate is considerable and
>   therefore Goal must be fairly expensive before one reaches a speedup.

To make a *goal fairly expensive*, I modified the code as:

```
% putting 1K pred/2 in heavy_pred/2 
concurrent_maplist(heavy_pred, List_of_64_List_of_1k_In, List_of_64_List_of_1k_Out).

heavy_pred(List_of_In, List_of_Out) :-
  maplist(pred, List_of_In, List_of_Out).
```

Surprisingly (for me), I do not get further speed up with this change.

I wonder how to get further speed up with multi-threading?

**Some additional details**:

Architecture: `x86_64, AMD, 14.04.1-Ubuntu`.

swipl -v: `SWI-Prolog version 6.6.4 for amd64`.

pred/2 is a theorem prover which takes formulas and tries to prove them.
It uses standard predicates with few non-standard ones: `cyclic_term/1`, `write/1`, `copy_term/2`, etc.

Comment: could be that your machine has 8 cores ?

Comment: Are you also loading `library(apply_macros)` to optimize the `maplist/3` call?

Comment: @Capellic, `current_prolog_flag(cpu_count, 64)` succeeds. @Paulo No I do not load it. Can you provide the source why do I need it for `concurrent_maplist`?

Comment: What is the actual hardware?  What does pred/2 do?  Which version of SWI-Prolog.  The 7.3.x series scales much better than the 7.2.x series on many concurrency issues.

Comment: @JanWielemaker I added requested details. From your reply I assume that the swipl version could be a main issue.

Comment: Surely, 1-10 sec will not screw up concurrent_maplist.  The overhead will get dominant if the concurrent work is in the low microsecond range, not in the seconds.  Write/1 locks and may screw up depending on how many writes are done.  First step would be to use the 7.3. versions.  Ideally try the latest GIT snapshot as today an issue with thread_local predicates was improved.

Answer (score 0):

To make your cores to work, you can use threads that can be fired up by your application. Using the very latest swipl version may help you get the latest improvements it offers.

You can also fire up several applications, each running e.g. 8 threads. Result: more cores would get work, albeit the total will take up more memory than running a single application with more threads. Now, you will need to manage the different application instances so that the overall job progresses (and don't repeat work done on other apps). I imagine that this is needed even in the case of a single application with more threads. My answer is not very technically steeped, but would get you to use more cores for a cpu intensive job.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-core CPUs don't scale linearly when the results are merged. I checked whether there is a difference between concurrent_maplist/2 and the new concurrent_and/2. I am using an example that has fairly large work items from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57060301/502187).

I added testing for concurrent_maplist/2:

```
/* parallel, concurrent_maplist */
count3(N) :-
   findall(Y, between(1, 1000, Y), L),
   concurrent_maplist(slice, L, R),
   aggregate_all(sum(M), member(M, R), N).
```

Interestingly there is not much difference between concurrent_and/2 and concurrent_maplist/2. Possibly because the number of work items is only 1000, due to the fairly larger work item itself. Nevertheless 1'000'000 numbers were check for primality:

```
?- current_prolog_flag(cpu_count, X).
X = 8.

/* sequential */
?- time(count(N)).
% 138,647,812 inferences, 9.781 CPU in 9.792 seconds (100% CPU, 14174856 Lips)
N = 78499.

/* parallel, concurrent_and */
?- time(count2(N)).
% 4,450 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 2.458 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
N = 78499.

/* parallel, concurrent_maplist */
?- time(count3(N)).
% 23,183 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 2.423 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
N = 78499.
```

Although the machine had 8 logical cores, thanks to hyper threading. The speed-up is close to the number of physical cores, which is only 4. So in case of your machine with 64 logical cores, that is what cpu_count Prolog flag returns, you should check how many physical cores there are.